# Android studio проблема со сборкой проекта

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь собрать пустой проект Hello World

выдает вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9079c9694b4d4270d7cd62242948af25\transformed\appcompat-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\112c0a3e5dbc3b1dd7ba5c1504be4543\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\40129cdd0cc6fb43e1431d3a7f860d71\transformed\jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\beb1e8c1d1724370afa1be71eb324942\transformed\jetified-emoji2-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\21249a56641fb0309777a5ae16ce99ff\transformed\core-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4d87c3e3b70abeed5e61faf08f3b9b5b\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0d7ad5a9bb64a79e832ad9e2795069b5\transformed\lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

на сколько я понимаю проблема с каими то зависимостями,телефон подключил студия его видит,подскажите как можно исправить проблему)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: minCompileSdk сделай 30. или зайди в зависимости и все на желтом фоне правой кнопкой - исправить на...

Answer (score 0):

Установить как **compileSdkVersion**, так и **targetSdkVersion**, в 31 в вашем **build.gradle(app)** файле:

```
android { 
    compileSdkVersion 31 //Здесь

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medinq.myclock"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdkVersion 31 //И здесь
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    } 
}
```